# ARJ under GNU/Linux

Tags: backup

I'm using ARJ compressor under GNU/Linux system to backup mostly FS with a size of 600 GBs aprox., and very large number of files. I'm not using compression, only store with split of 50GB volumes.

So, when ARJ start, it spend so much time to create the first file of volumes. Then additional volumes are copied with "normal" speed.

There is any option to start inmediatly with the first volume.
I'm using this parameters:

```
arj a -jyk -i -r -m0 -vw50000000k <arj_file> <base_directory>
```

Comment: use `tar` and `split` on unix, otherwise you'll lose meta-data like owner, group, permissions, and non-files like hard and symbolic links.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Hi cas ! Thanks, but I haven't option with the tool, we only may use arj because it is a requeriment :-( . I don't need store meta-data.

Comment: dang. i havent heard that word in a *long* time. i think i downloaded an ARJed *jazz jackrabbit* more than twenty years ago. i though ARJ died w/ pirate BBSes?

Comment: The question, is there any parameter to start without analize the source file system ?
I think that arj analized first source file system before to start any action on destiny.

xDDD yes mikeserv, really. It's really an obsolete tool, but is very fast compared with another tools.

Comment: It's solved !! We are using tar xD
With these parameters:

tar -vc -M --tape-length=${filesize} --file ${file} --new-volume-script="/opt/pso/bin/newtarvol.sh ${t\
    o} `basename ${file}`" ${exclusions[*]} ${src} | tee -a ${logact}

Thanks to all !!